# A composite number containing exactly 1993 digits "1" and one digit "7"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Give an example of a composite number whose decimal representation contains exactly

1. $1994$ digits "$1$" and a digit "$7$" (and no other digit).
2. $1993$ digits "$1$" and a digit "$7$" (and no other digit).

I think the first one goes with any number that contains $1994$ digits "$1$" and a digit "$7$" because the sum would be divisible by $3$ and then the number is composite but I can't see how to find the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct for the first.

Hint:  For the second, if the $7$ is in the $10^n$ place your number is $1111...1 (1994$ ones) $+ 6\cdot 10^n$.  What is the remainder of dividing the number with all the $1$s by $7$?  Can you find an $n$ that makes the sum divisible by $7?$

Comment: The main part of your answer I can see. But, $7 \equiv_3 1$, and $3$ does not divide $1994$, so how can a number w $1994$ digits [or for that matter $1993$ digits], all $7$ or $1$  be divisible by $3$?

Comment: Problem solved ! Thank you so much